# Finding common string in list and displaying them

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, python-requests

I am trying to create a function compare(lst1,lst2) which compares the each element in a list and returns every common element in a new list and shows percentage of how common it is. All the elements in the list are going to be strings. For example the function should return:

```
lst1 = AAAAABBBBBCCCCCDDDD
lst2 = ABCABCABCABCABCABCA
common strand = AxxAxxxBxxxCxxCxxxx
similarity = 25%
```

The parts of the list which are not similar will simply be returned as x.
I am having trouble in completing this function without the python **set** and **zip** method. I am not allowed to use them for this task and I have to achieve this using while and for loops. Kindly guide me as to how I can achieve this.

Comment: Please share your code that you have tried.

Comment: just iterate over the string using a for loop and compare one character from each string (or list) at a time keeping count of how many characters are the same while also building the common strand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what I came up with.

```
lst1 = 'AAAAABBBBBCCCCCDDDD'
lst2 = 'ABCABCABCABCABCABCA'
common_strand = ''

score = 0
for i in range(len(lst1)):
    if lst1[i] == lst2[i]:
        common_strand = common_strand + str(lst1[i])
        score += 1
    else:
        common_strand = common_strand + 'x'

print('Common Strand: ', common_strand)
print('Similarity Score: ', score/len(lst1))
```

Output:

```
Common Strand:  AxxAxxxBxxxCxxCxxxx
Similarity Score:  0.2631578947368421
```

Answer (score 1):

> I am having trouble in completing this function without the python set and zip method. I am not allowed to use them for this task and I have to achieve this using while and for loops. Kindly guide me as to how I can achieve this.

You have two strings `A` and `B`. Strings are ordered sequences of characters.

Suppose both `A` and `B` have equal length (the same number of characters). Choose some position `i < len(A), len(B)` (remember Python sequences are 0-indexed). Your problem statement requires:

1. If character `i` in `A` is identical to character `i` in `B`, yield that character
2. Otherwise, yield some placeholder to denote the mismatch

How do you find the `i`th character in some string `A`? [Take a look at Python's string methods](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#string-methods). Remember: strings are *sequences* of characters, so Python strings *also* implement several [sequence-specific operations](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#typesseq-common).

If `len(A) != len(B)`, you need to decide what to do if you're comparing the `i`th element in either string to a string smaller than `i`. You might think to represent these as the same placeholder in (2).

If you know how to iterate the result of `zip`, you know how to use `for` loops. All you need is a way to iterate over the sequence of indices. [Check out the language built-in functions](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html).

Finally, for your measure of similarity: if you've compared `n` characters and found that `N <= n` are mismatched, you can define `1 - (N / n)` as your measure of similarity. This works well for equally-long strings (for two strings with different lengths, you're always going to be calculating the proportion relative to the *longer* string).